# Django REST with React: axios PATCH with FormData not updating any data

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I am trying to make a form that edits the user's profile data and uses the patch method to change all the fields except the username because the username is the primary key and only identifier of a specific user.

**Update:**

-**I changed it to a regular PATCH method and the data does not update**

-**I also made sure formData sends the correct data, which it does**

From reading previous questions, I've learned that a normal *axios.patch* method does not work with *FormData* and I've followed the instructions of adding:

*formData.append("_method", "PATCH")*

and changing the axios method to *axios.put*, however, I still receive a 400 error which states, in the data section:

> username: ["This field is required."]

Help would be much appreciated. Thank you, kind strangers!

**Edit Profile Submit:**

```
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { firstName, lastName, profile } = this.state;
    const username = localStorage.getItem("username");
    formData.append("_method", "PATCH");
    formData.append("firstName", firstName);
    formData.append("lastName", lastName);
    formData.append("profile_picture", profile);
    this.props.onUpdate(formData, username);
  };
```

**Axios Request**

```
export const userUpdate = (formData, username) => {
  axios
    .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/api/${username}`, {
      formData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
};
```

**User models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, default='Anonymous')
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length = 25, blank = True, default='')
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    profile_picture = models.ForeignKey('upload.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**Profile Picture models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to=profile_path, default='f_profile.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to be using `PATCH` if you want a `patch` request.

```
export const userUpdate = (formData, username) => {
  axios
    .patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/api/${username}`, {
      formData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
};
```

Also, drop the `_method` from the form. Unless you have a specific view to make something of it, you won't need it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want it to make a PATCH request so that the username doesn't have to be re-submitted (to my understanding that is what a patch request is but correct me if I'm wrong). I also tried the PUT request and it still gave me the same 400 error.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my answer, should have said `patch` instead of `put`

Comment: With this method it sends the `PATCH` request properly with a 200 code, however, the data does not change at all from what it was before sending the request. Is there a weird nuance that I missed?

Comment: ps: I also made sure that the formData was sends all of the correct data in it, which it does.